# Losing preview ability: W3 Total Cache + Post name permalinks

Tags: permalinks, plugin-w3-total-cache, cache, previews

I've been seeing issues on sites when I enable W3 Total Cache (Using an aws cdn) where the ability to preview pages would be lost.

I was just able to confirm this when enabling it on a new site.

A few other notes:
- Previews work as long as the permalink is NOT set to "Post Name."

Otherwise, this error displays "Sorry, you are not allowed to preview drafts" which leads me to believe the security token comparison is false.

Anyone have experience or workarounds to get previews working with caching enabled?

Thanks!